# Is there a Linux terminal command for creating .xlsx files from .bracken files in a loop in a new folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, cat

Is there a loop I can use to create .xlsx files from `.bracken` files I currently have and channel them into an output folder?
All that I have now is to convert my `.bracken` files into `.xlsx` files using this code `cat MG-ABCD12345-0.genus.bracken > MG-ABCD12345-0_genus_bracken.xlsx` and files are going into my current working directory. I would like the output in a folder called `bracken_excel_files` which is located within my current working directory. I would prefer to use common commands such as `for` for the loop for easier understanding.

Comment: I never heard of "bracken" files, but renaming a file to "*.xlsx" looks a weird idea. Is renaming to "*.csv" a better idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is your problem related to programming?

Comment: In case you don't understand, "cat" is a simple "read line then output unmodified line" action.

Answer (score 0):

[bracken](/questions/tagged/bracken) appears to be generating/sharing the same output format as [kraken](/questions/tagged/kraken), which I saw somewhere to be **tab-delimited fields**.

If that is true, then that is the essence of what **CSV** files are.

In that case, you don't need to use the "cat" command (CPU and I/O consuming).  You simply need to **rename** the file with a "**.csv**" suffix (*to make the file format explicitly visible for others*), **then** import that into *Excel* or *OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc*.  Each of those tools offer different options for interpreting the input when you use the "**Import**" function to open the files.